# Difference running the same script from Windows than Linux

Tags: files, conversion

I've written a script that run unoconv, converts from csv to xls.

I run it connecting using openssh client to the server where script is and it works fine. (Always the same Linux user...)

But when other person using putty from Windows run that script, unoconv fails, rendering numbers as text.

The script always is run on Linux server.

The difference is that some fields are prepended with a "'" (single quote). For example, let says one field has:
**0,80**
When running using putty on Windows it produces **'0,80**
Version unoconv is

```
unoconv 0.7 Written by Dag Wieers <dag@wieers.com> Homepage at http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/

platform posix/linux2 python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] LibreOffice 4.2.8.2
```

What could be the reason for such a difference?

Comment: Numbers are technically text; can you show an example of the difference?

Comment: Only difference is that one field, it appends a " ' " (single quote) por example in Linux it shows 0,80, while from Windows '0,80

Comment: Are both of you running the exact same unoconv command? What is it?

Comment: Yes the are: `unoconv -i FilterOptions=44,34,76 -f xls  ${ARCHIVOINFO}.csv`

Comment: Please edit your question to add a sample input file that shows a difference, and post the output of `unoconv --version` on both machines.

Comment: @Gilles unoconv is always the same, because run from the server, such as the post  says it.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the reason:

Eariler my script replaced with command sed each "." with ","

Because it's the decimal separator that we use.

I've found that unoconv manages smartly this issues:

https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options

I've found a workaround:

```
echo  "Se esta conectando desde Windows o Linux (físico)?. Elija el SO por favor. Escriba 'Windows' o 'Linux'."

read OS


if [[ $OS = Linux ]];then
   sed -i 's/\./,/g' ${ARCHIVOINFO}.csv
fi
```

I need to convert "." por "," if run the script from Linux client otherwise it fails preprending the single quote.

Perhaps there is a better solution, but it works fine for me by now.